botが接続されたときにミュートされる
理想
参加したときにそのままミュートせずに音が流れる
実際の結果
参加したときにミュートされる。
今までに試したこと

サーバーミュートしてからサーバーミュート解除すると音が流れる。しかしできる限りやりたくない。
Google検索で調べても出てこなかった。

import discord
import asyncio

@app_command.command()
@app_command.describe(channel="接続先")
async def connect(interaction: discord.Interaction, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    vc = await channel.connect()

    try:
        while True:
            if interaction.guild.voice_client is None:
                break
            vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("sound.wav"))
            while vc.is_playing():
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    except:
        pass


自己解決しました。 追記: 自己解決しませんでした 追記: 解決しました
ChatGPTに聞いてみたところ、Botが接続直後にミュートされているか確認し、必要であればミュート解除を行うコードを追加すればよかったようです。
https://chatgpt.com/share/c7cae2d4-1974-4bbb-a47f-cf0262e800b1
修正後
import discord
import asyncio

@app_command.command()
@app_command.describe(channel="接続先")
async def connect(interaction: discord.Interaction, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    vc = await channel.connect()

    if interaction.guild.voice_client.is_mute:
        await interaction.guild.voice_client.edit(mute=False)

    try:
        while True:
            if interaction.guild.voice_client is None:
                break
            vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("sound.wav"))
            while vc.is_playing():
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    except:
        pass

追記:
上記のコードで成功しませんでした。ChatGPTに聞いてみたところ、別のコードで実行できたんですが、メンバーのミュート管理の権限が必要なようです。
さらに追記:
別のチャンネルでやると行けました!
